# codeigniter mvc , model separation

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, model

Here is my problem in codeigniter MVC.

Suppose I have 3 models: (users, email , payments).
When some one paid by some way , controller calls some method of payments model , that method could be called from other controllers too.

That method , does some database insert and update and at the end , it wants to send an email to user , it already has userid , but it needs username , email , which should get from users table and then send email.

I don't like payments model could have access to users table and I want to get info from users model and send email using email model.

normally I call those from controller , I mean first call payments model and get the result and get users info from users model and then use email model , all in controller .

But because I need to run that model's method in some controllers , I must repeat those lines and it is not the correct aspect in my point.

Question:
Should I call other models inside model or use other models tables inside model (in this option , if I want to reuse that model I should change it if other tables changed which is not right) , or is there any other way?

The main problem is not exactly that one it is just example of situation .
I also defined some function which does those thing and call from controllers , but it is not right too.

Comment: if all methods was at the same model I had no problem. but it is not right too.

Comment: I am using CI for 3 months and I faced some limitation , so do you think if I use zend framework , will it helpful , in this case and other limitation , Ie : defining multi layer controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it all into a library.

So your controller calls the library for a "payment", and passes some details. Your library then does ALL of the features you describe above - i.e. calls the payment model, sends the email etc etc.

[You can learn more about codeigniter libraries here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Comment: Thanks , it is an option , can you tell me what is different between function and library in this case , and if I can use function in this approach , after all I wanted to put all logic in a class in this case Model.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great solution. Define My_model.php in application/core.

```
Class My_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get($where , $table){
        $query = $this->db->get_where($table, $where);
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Now you model should extend My_model instead of CI_Model.
And now you can call it like this. Let suppose in your controller you have loaded email model and you want to access user model.

```
 $where = array('user_id', $id); 
 $table = 'user';
 $this->email->get($table, $where);
```

For more information read this book
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/211821/

Comment: This is some solution but it is not exact point I am looking for.